# Working out decimal odds

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Going over some old code

```
<!--- RANDOMLY DECIDE IS THIS PERSONS A WINNER 1 IN 8 CHANCE--->
<cfset attributes.random_point = RandRange(1, 8)>

<cfif attributes.random_point eq 5>
  WINNER
<cfelse>
  You got nothing!
</cfif>
```

How do I convert this to decimal odds? From now on I want to use the decimal odds to determine the change of getting x. So for example I have a 1.10 chance or 1.11 chance of getting x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly then I would define the % chance of winning as a decimal and then rely on Rand(), though this still doesn't feel ideal

```
<cfscript>
    numChanceToWin = 0.15;  // <= this == winner == 15% chance to win
    numRandom = Rand(); // decimal from 0 to 1

    if (numRandom <= numChanceToWin ) {
        // Winner
    } else {
        // Loser
    }
<cfscript>
```

Also works with your 1/8 definition by setting `numChanceToWin = 1/8;` or even `if (numRandom/numChanceToWin <= 1) { // Winner`

Answer (score 1):

I would simply make the attributes.random_point a randrange(1,100)/100

```
<!--- RANDOMLY DECIDE IS THIS PERSONS A WINNER 1 IN 8 CHANCE--->
<cfset attributes.random_point = RandRange(0, 100)/100>

<cfif attributes.random_point lt 0.11>
  WINNER
<cfelse>
  You got nothing!
</cfif>
```